# Encode image to photobase64

Tags: flutter

I am encoding the image to photobase64 but I am only getting parts of the image. The encoded code given to me is not the full code.

```
 Future pickGallery() async {
try {
  final pickedImage = await ImagePicker().pickImage(
    source: ImageSource.gallery,
  );
  if (pickedImage != null) {
    image = File(pickedImage.path);
    List<int> photobytes = await image!.readAsBytes();
    setState(() {
      String photobase = convert.base64Encode(photobytes);
      print(photobase);
    });
  } else {
    Utils.showAlertSnackBar('No image selected.');
  }
} on PlatformException catch (e) {
  print('Failed to pick image: $e');
}
```

}

This encoded code below gave me this [result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zP95j.jpg)

```
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
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Using `print()` gives limited results. Therefore, I used `log()` to show the full the photobase64 code.